# will android development on device damage the device?

Tags: android

I would like to know if intensive android development using device can damage the device itself?

I ask this because my last samsung phone had motherboard damaged during development.

Will frequent uploading and running dev version app have any harm to the phone. How about the exceptions that may happen?

In any other circumstance can the device be damaged? Maybe it's not software related?

Comment: Depends on how you use the device while doing development.

Comment: Doing it 2 years with mine now, 4 days a week. But it still works like a charm, no difference when I got the phone. But, 1 time I made an app with a leak (sadly) that drained the battery faster then charger could charge it (went down 1% every 15 minutes while on charger, pretty amazing to be honest, it is some kind of achievement :D). I can guess when you do that all day, the device can get overheated :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every application in android runs by default in a sandbox. Accessing system resources outside that is completely dependant on the permissions you explicitly provide in the application manifest. Exceptions are limited to the application usually, no further.

Uploading and running is no different than installing and un-installing application from the Play store, so no reason to worry there. Sure, there is the wear of the flash memory cells, but it is so minimal it isn't worth mentioning.

Damaging a device on the hardware level is possible only if you are messing with system parameters such as clock speed, voltages etc. which I doubt you will. On the software level you may manage to corrupt some system files with some effort, but it will most certainly require root privileges and a certain know-how. Your previous Samsung handset may have been defective, but if you are so worried, you can always use an emulator like the one provided in the ADT Bundle.

In short, no, not really.

Comment: luckily I got my question answered. Thanks aBrav!