# Trouble setting up android studio emulator

Tags: cordova, android-studio

I have recently decided to make an attempt at getting an app made and published to the play store but I've encountered a problem I can't seem to find a fix for. After installing Node.js, Git, Java, Gradle, Android Studio and Cordova I've tried launching Pixel Q emulator both from CLI, where it leaves me "waiting for emulator to start" forever, as well as from within Android Studio where it opens for a moment and closes right away. Android Studio console gives various errors. Most related to a sound/audio/voice problem I think may be unrelated. One says quick boot / snapshots not supported. The last one, which I think may point to the cause of the problem, says "requested RAM 1536M too high for your system. Reducing to maximum supported size 512M". I've tried several suggestions I found online but to no avail. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've never had any luck with emulators, they're either too slow or not working at all. My solution was to use a real phone. That way you can test your app in an easy and fast way.

Comment: I have been considering doing that as a last resort if I am unable to fix. Can I use my personal device or should it be one designated for development only? Are there any risks to the device being used?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea but I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/14937853/10262090.

Comment: Well at least that alleviates some of the concern I had if I end up going with plan B. Thanks!